# How does an AMI create processes?

Tags: amazon-ami

I understand, that creating an image copies that system, but how does this work with processes?

Does a new AMI start each momentarily running process from the beginning or is the running process snapshotted and continued?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running processes are not part of an AMI. An AMI captures the contents of the instance's disk. The new instance launched from the AMI will boot from scratch, and if you want anything to run on the instance it needs to be configured to run at boot (for example, as a service). By default, the AMI creation process shuts the instance down before capturing a snapshot of its disk and then boots it back up afterwards. While you can choose to suppress this behavior and take the snapshot of the running instance, this doesn't have the effect of preserving the system RAM or running processes, and when a new instance is launched the state will be equivalent to the source instance having been powered off (without a clean shutdown) and rebooted.

Comment: ah, I  get it. my webserver is configured the way, that it starts at restart, thank you!